# Use `$options` in an `EntityType` Query_builder

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder, formbuilder

I use a Form Builder to create my form. I added the option *team* to the `FormBuilderInterface` to access this property in my form.

```php
class PersonnalStatType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tag', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => StatTag::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (StatTagRepository $rep/*, $options*/)
                    {
                        return $rep->queryActivated($options['team']);
                    }
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => PersonnalStat::class,
            'team' => null
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('team', ['null', Team::class]);
    }
```

The first row is an `EntityType` and I need to use the *team* option to perform a query but I don't know how to proceed.

So far I tried :

```php
'query_builder' => function (StatTagRepository $rep)
    {
        return $rep->queryActivated($options['team']);
    }
```

but the query doesn't know `$options`

> Notice: Undefined variable: options

And

```php
'query_builder' => function (StatTagRepository $rep, $options)
    {
        return $rep->queryActivated($options['team']);
    }
```

but it doesn't recognize `$options`

> Too few arguments to function App\Form\PersonnalStatType::App\Form{closure}(), 1 passed in /Users/pierrickrambaud/Sites/team-manager/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Form/Type/EntityType.php on line 32 and exactly 2 expected

Anyone knows a hack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```php
'query_builder' => function (StatTagRepository $rep) use ($options) {
    return $rep->queryActivated($options['team']);
}
```

Comment: just for me to better understand, the `function` parameters are the callback and with the `use` I can add custom param ?

Comment: The `use` allows to pass in parameters from the parent scope into the anonymous function, which by default has it's own scope (inside the class). See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-167